# Deploying from Octopus Deploy to Scaled Azure App Service

Tags: azure, octopus-deploy

If an App Service Plan containing an App Service is horizontally scaled in Azure (using Monitor - Auto scale functionality) how does that affect future deployments via Octopus if the "Deploy to Azure" step is used. Would any deployments automatically get deployed to all scaled instances in Azure without us having to do any more configuration in Octopus?

Answer (score 0):

Octopus will not automatically deploy to scaled instances without configuration. You will need to configure Octopus to automatically deploy to targets using project triggers. You can find documentation on using project triggers here: https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/project-triggers/automatic-deployment-triggers and documentation specifically concerning auto-scaling infrastructure here: https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-patterns/elastic-and-transient-environments/keeping-deployment-targets-up-to-date

Comment: When using app Service I think the instances get abstracted from you when you scale out, they aren't like virtual machines.  I am going to scale out an app service to 3 instances as a test, deploy via octopus log out the assembly version number and something to identify the app service instance to give some clarity one way or the other.

Comment: What was the result of this experiment, @willd1985?